# Strange exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location must not be null or empty

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello everyone was doing a posting app was all good but I wanted to implement to put user profile photos and it will be rescued in the post fragment, in the user frgment like all profile photo but it gives me this error,
Try to do the same as in the fragement dialog to upload photos but it does not work

the exeption:

```
 03-25 14:22:12.567 22927-22927/com.android.octa.memetixs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.android.octa.memetixs, PID: 22927
                                                                       Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location must not be null or empty
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReference(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.android.octa.memetixs.ui.fragment.UserFragment.onCreateView(UserFragment.java:67)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2899)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1224)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewR
```

the fragment user:
(When I implement the method to upload photo gave me the error)

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment {


private View mRootView;
private ImageView mUserImage;
private TextView mUsername;
private ImageButton mChangePhotoUser, mLogOut;
private Uri mSelectedImageUri;
private User mUser;
private Post mPost;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

private final static int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;

public UserFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    init();
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(mUser.getPhotUrl());
    Glide.with(getActivity()).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(mUserImage);

    return mRootView;
}

private void init(){
    final String userId = FirebaseUtils.getUid();
    mUserImage = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUser_fragUser);
    mUsername = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername_fragUser);
    mLogOut = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonExit_FragUser);
    mChangePhotoUser = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPhoto_fragUser);
    mUser = new User();

    mChangePhotoUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });

    if(mSelectedImageUri != null){
        FirebaseUtils.getImagesUserRef().child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(mSelectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
             String url = Constants.USER_IMAGE + "/" + mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment();
               mUser.setPhotUrl(url);


                addToMyOtherList(userId);

            }
        });



    }else{
        addToMyOtherList(userId);
    }



  mLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        logOut();
      }
  });


}

private void logOut(){
    mAuth.signOut();
}


private void addToMyOtherList(String imageId){
    FirebaseUtils.getUserImageProfileRef().child(imageId).setValue(mUser);
    FirebaseUtils.getMyUserProfileRef().child(imageId).setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
          // null
        }
    });
  FirebaseUtils.addToMyOtherRecord(Constants.USER_IMAGE_KEY, imageId);
}

private void selectImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
            mUserImage.setImageURI(mSelectedImageUri);
        }
    }

}
```

}

I took the example of this class to upload the user photo

```
 public class PostCreateDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 1;
private View mRootView;
private Post mPost;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Uri mSelectedImageUri;
private ImageView mPostDisplay;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    mPost = new Post();

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    mRootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_create_dialog, null);
    mPostDisplay = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_display);
    mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview).setOnClickListener(this);
    mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview).setOnClickListener(this);
    builder.setView(mRootView);
    return builder.create();


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview:
            sendPost();
            break;
        case R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview:
            selectImage();
            break;
    }
}


private void selectImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
}

private void sendPost(){
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Sending post...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.show();

    FirebaseUtils.getUserRef(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","))
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    final String postUid = FirebaseUtils.getUid();
                    TextView postDialogTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_edittext);
                    String text = postDialogTextView.getText().toString();

                    mPost.setUser(user);
                    mPost.setNumComments(0);
                    mPost.setNumLikes(0);
                    mPost.setTimeCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    mPost.setPostId(postUid);
                    mPost.setPostText(text);

                    if (mSelectedImageUri != null) {
                        FirebaseUtils.getImagesSRef()
                                .child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment())
                                .putFile(mSelectedImageUri)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(),
                                        new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                String url = Constants.POST_IMAGES + "/" + mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment();
                                                //String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                                mPost.setPostImageUrl(url);
                                                addToMyPostList(postUid);
                                            }


                                        });
                    } else {
                        addToMyPostList(postUid);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}

private void addToMyPostList(final String postUid){
    FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postUid)
            .setValue(mPost);
    FirebaseUtils.getMyPostRef().child(postUid).setValue(true)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

    FirebaseUtils.addToMyRecord(Constants.POSTS_KEY, postUid);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
            mPostDisplay.setImageURI(mSelectedImageUri);
        }
    }

}
```

}

And finally the "utils" class here are the references

i created a another method "addToMyotherRecord"
for adding the user prodile photo but not works

```
public class FirebaseUtils {
public static DatabaseReference getUserRef(String email) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.USERS_KEYS)
            .child(email);
}

public static DatabaseReference getUserImageProfileRef(){
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_IMAGE_KEY);
}

public static DatabaseReference getMyUserProfileRef(){
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.MY_USER_IMAGE).child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".",","));
}

public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_KEY);
}

public static Query getPostQuery() {
    return getPostRef().orderByChild(Constants.TIME_CREATED_KEY);
}

public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_LIKED_KEY);
}

public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef(String postId) {
    return getPostLikedRef().child(getCurrentUser().getEmail()
            .replace(".", ","))
            .child(postId);
}

public static FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
}

public static String getUid() {
    String path = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().toString();
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}

public static StorageReference getImagesSRef() {
    return FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(Constants.POST_IMAGES);
}

public static StorageReference getImagesUserRef(){
    return FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_IMAGE);
}

public static DatabaseReference getMyPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.MY_POSTS)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}

public static DatabaseReference getCommentRef(String postId) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.COMMENTS_KEY)
            .child(postId);
}

public static DatabaseReference getMyRecordRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_RECORD)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}

public static void addToMyOtherRecord(String node, final String id){
    FirebaseUtils.getMyRecordRef().child(node).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            ArrayList<String> myUserImageCollection;
            if(mutableData.getValue() == null){
                myUserImageCollection = new ArrayList<>(1);
                myUserImageCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myUserImageCollection);
            }else{
                myUserImageCollection = (ArrayList<String>) mutableData.getValue();
                myUserImageCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myUserImageCollection);
            }
         return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}

public static void addToMyRecord(String node,final String id) {
    FirebaseUtils.getMyRecordRef().child(node).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            ArrayList<String> myPostCollection;
            if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                myPostCollection = new ArrayList<>(1);
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            } else {
                myPostCollection = (ArrayList<String>) mutableData.getValue();
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

and the constants

```
 public class Constants {
public static final String POSTS_KEY = "posts";
public static final String TIME_CREATED_KEY = "timeCreated";
public static final String NUM_LIKES_KEY = "numLikes";
public static final String POSTS_LIKED_KEY = "posts_liked";
public static final String EXTRA_POST_ID = "postId";
public static final String POST_IMAGES = "post_images";
public static final String USER_IMAGE = "user_imagee";
public static final String MY_USER_IMAGE  = "my_profileeImages";
public static final String USER_IMAGE_KEY = "userImage_key"; // se agrega al record
public static final String MY_POSTS = "my_posts";
public static final String EXTRA_POST = "post";
public static final String COMMENTS_KEY = "comments";
public static final String USER_RECORD = "user_record";
public static final String NUM_SHARES_KEY = "numShares";
public static String USERS_KEYS = "users";
```

}

Comment: StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(mUser.getPhotUrl()); I suspect the getPhtoUrl() is returning null because the image has not been uploaded yet.

Comment: UserFragment.java:67 please give the code on this line ?

Comment: @ChesterCobus all of user fragment its here , but yes im working in this,

Comment: I just need line 67, there are no line numbers in this code snippet.

Comment: is this     all the onCreateView i think the error is in storageReferece      ´ public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    init();
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(mUser.getPhotUrl());
    Glide.with(getActivity()).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(mUserImage);

    return mRootView;
}´   @ChesterCobus

Comment: thanks. I think you need to have this : gs://{appname}.appspot.com in FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("gs://{appname}.appspot.com"); you do not have this link to upload to firebase.

Comment: thanks i implement this, @ChesterCobus